# Render form on same screen when clicking a button on React, and also saving it on props file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I want to make the button with the FaPlus icon to render a form OnClick (or OnPress, i've seen that's an option too but i don't know if it makes any difference in comparison) but React says "añadirCurso" (the arrow function) is not defined, any ideas? (i was using part of the code of another question similar to this, but maybe it doesn't work because that code was in a class that extended Component)

Here's the code

```
import React from "react";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import {aulas} from '../props/aulas';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import {FaPlus} from 'react-icons/fa';
import { Route, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function AdministrarCurso_Preceptor(){
    const navigate= useNavigate();
    const state= {añadirCurso: false};
    añadirCurso= () =>{
        return (
            <div>
                <form method="GET" action="#">
                    <legend>Añadir Curso</legend>
                    <label htmlFor="usuario">Nombre de Usuario</label> <br/>
                    <input required type="text" name="usuario" defaultValue="" /> <br/>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
    return(
        <Container>
            <AppBar style={{background: 'transparent', boxShadow: 'none'}}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Button className="btn btn-success" sx={{flexGrow: 1}}>
                        <FaPlus/>
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={()=> navigate('/LoginForm')}>Cerrar Sesión</Button>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar> 
            <div className="row">
                {/* Acá hay un map que muestra todo el contenido del prop aulas 
                y le asigna un botón dentro de filas y columnas hechas 
                mientras se toma el contenido del array */}
            {aulas.map((aula, i)  => (
                <div key={i} className="col-md-4" style={{paddingBottom: '10px', paddingTop: '5px'}}>
                <Button className={(aula.estado==='sucio'? 'btn btn-danger': 'btn btn-success')}>{aula.año}{aula.division}</Button>
                </div>
            ))}
            </div>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

And for the "saving it on props" part, as i've said in a previous question i have a props file with classrooms (aulas) and i want the form data to save in that file on Submit, so that when you click on the submit button it saves the data there, and since it's in that file, it should render a new button, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons regarding why your code is not working.

1. First of all, as you mentioned the code belonged to a class component and it seems like you simply pasted that in your functional component.
2. You need to use const before the arrow function's name.
3. Rather than returning JSX, I'd highly (like really highly) recommend you to use a state like

   const [isFormVisible, setIsFormVisible] = useState(false);

and then on click of the button, you just set the state to true. and use the variable for conditional rendering like this....

```
{isFormVisible && (<theJSXGoesHere />)}
```

Comment: Should i make the code to extend Component though? Or will making it just like this do the trick?

Comment: No you don't need to (and neither can) extend cause that's only for class based components.

Comment: Okay, i couldn't do it, is this what i should be doing?

`const state= {añadirCurso: false};
    const [Form,setForm] = useState(false);
    const añadirCurso= () =>{
        if (Form==true){
            return (<theform>)}

<Button className="btn btn-success" sx={{flexGrow: 1}} onChange={(setForm)=> setForm(true)}>
                        <FaPlus/>
                    </Button>`